# ECharts - set axisPointer positioning to vertical (time type)

Tags: javascript, charts, data-visualization, echarts

I am using [ECharts](https://web.archive.org/web/20180321222746/http://ecomfe.github.io:80/echarts/index-en.html) to plot a simple line graph that displays data about CPU usage over a period of time. I want the xAxis to only have 6 intervals, which are hourly; between each interval there are values for every half hour. I also want the axisPointer to be vertical, not horizontal.

The problem is, that to do this I need to set the **xAxis** *type* to *time* and by doing this is makes the axisPointer change to horizontal, instead of vertical. In the image below you can see how the axisPointer looks in vertical orientation with the *category* type.

[image: vertical axisPointer]
<sub>(source: [zips.me](https://i.zips.me/212bzn5wd4d43Qe.png))</sub>

Here you can see what my chart looks like and what I am trying to explain,
[image: myChart]

Finally, this is the code used to make my graph.

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('myChart'));
var option = {
 grid: {
        x: 40,
        x2: 40,
        y: 35,
        y2: 25
    },
    // Add tooltip
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis',
    },

    color: ['#EF5350', '#66BB6A'],

    calculable: false,

    // Horizontal axis
    xAxis: [{
        type: 'time',
    }],

    // Vertical axis
    yAxis: [{
        type: 'value',
        axisLabel: {
            formatter: '{value}%'
        }
    }],

    series: [
        {
            name: 'CPU',
            type: 'line',
            showAllSymbol: true,
   tooltip: {
   trigger: 'axis',
    padding: 15,
    formatter: function(params, ticket, callback){
     var res = '<span style="font-weight: 600;">Today, ' + params[1].getHours() + ':' + params[1].getMinutes() + '</span><br/><hr>CPU: <span style="float: right;">' + params[2][1] + '%</span>';
     return res;
    }
   },
            data: (function(){
                var d = [];
                var tme = 10;
                var now = new Date();
                var value;
                while(tme++ < 16){
                    d.push([
                        new Date(2017, 3, 15, tme, 0), Math.floor(Math.random() * 85) + 25
                    ]);
     if(tme !==16){
      for(i = 5; i < 60; i+=5){
       d.push([
        new Date(2017, 3, 15, tme, i), Math.floor(Math.random() * 70) + 30
       ]);
      }
     }
                }
                return d;
            })()
        }
    ]
};

myChart.setOption(option);
```

```css
#myChart {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/2.2.0/echarts-all.js"></script>
<div id="myChart">

</div>
```